# how to specify directory paths in gitignore

Tags: git

part of my gitignore file looks like this:

```
phoenix/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php
StatsFile.txt
phoenix/StatsFile.txt
phoenix/config/*
phoenix/config/propel.ini
phoenix/data/*
phoenix/lib/filter/*
phoenix/lib/form/*
phoenix/lib/model/*
```

so the full path of for ex. the data directory will be:

```
/home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/data
```

my gitignore is in directory: /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code

it is not ignoring anything i have in my excerpt above???
am i misunderstanding how .gitignore works?
how must i specify the paths??
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible the gitignore file has a typo?

It should be *.gitignore* with a leading . in front.

Comment: yes i have it like that with the . infront

Comment: what on earth did i do when i ran: git -r rm --cached and straight after did git add . ???? yikes

Comment: What you did was to remove all you added to be committed previously and readded everything. Adding files to .gitignore will not remove them from your repo, it will just not add them again. To remove the files from the repo use 'git rm <filename>' till your project is spiffy clean and commit everything. From now on git should behave as expected.